# UIViewController default's behavior without XIB and without overriding loadView - documentation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I was wondering what was the behavior of the `UIViewController` subclass when you use `initWithNibName:bundle:` with `nil` arguments without overriding `loadView` and without having a corresponding XIB or NIB file in the bundle.

With a simple program, I display the property `self.view` in the debugger :

```
(lldb) po self.view
 <UIView: 0x15e8b440; frame = (0 0; 320 548); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x15e8a8b0>>
```

We can see that the class initialize a `UIView` whose frame has the same size as the `UIScreen.bounds`.

I did not find explanation in the Apple documentation. Is it explicitly  documented somewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for the [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) method:

> If the view controller has an associated nib file, this method loads
>   the view from the nib file. A view controller has an associated nib
>   file if the `nibName` property returns a non-`nil` value, which occurs if
>   the view controller was instantiated from a storyboard, if you
>   explicitly assigned it a nib file using the `initWithNibName:bundle:`
>   method, or if iOS finds a nib file in the app bundle with a name based
>   on the view controller’s class name.
>
> If the view controller does not
>   have an associated nib file, this method creates a plain `UIView` object
>   instead.